# Count json object by finding its value in php

Tags: php, json

I have this json data . How can count the object using `leader` i want to count `"leader": "true"`

this is my json: in this case the count of `"leader":"true"` is 1

```
[
{
"id":23,
"uid":"0090000219",
"cid":"0090000013",
"extension":"201",
"secret":"Myojyo42_f",
"leader":true,
"simultaneous":false,
"confbridge_id":17,
"created_at":"2015-09-02 12:49:12",
"updated_at":"2015-09-02 12:49:12"
},
{
"id":24,
"uid":"0090000221",
"cid":"0090000013",
"extension":"203",
"secret":"Myojyo42_f",
"leader":false,
"simultaneous":false,
"confbridge_id":17,
"created_at":"2015-09-02 12:49:12",
"updated_at":"2015-09-02 12:49:12"
},
{
"id":25,
"uid":"0090000223",
"cid":"0090000013",
"extension":"205",
"secret":"Myojyo42_f",
"leader":false,
"simultaneous":false,
"confbridge_id":17,
"created_at":"2015-09-10 10:16:24",
"updated_at":"2015-09-10 10:16:24"
}
]
```

This is my code:

```
        foreach($apiResults['conference_participants'] as &$record) {
           $leader_count = count(record['leader']);  
        }
```

Comment: Your true is a string? or Boolean?

Comment: its a Boolean @aldrin27

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decode it first then it will return then count the data `leader`.

Try this:

```
$decoded = json_decode($json, true);



     $count = 0;
    foreach($decoded as $key => $val)
    {
       if($val['leader'] == 1)
       {
           $count++;
       }
    }
    echo $count;
       //if you want also to count the false then add else in the statement echo  $count++;
    }
```

Comment: You should increment a variable inside of the if statement and then echo after the loop... if there are two leaders this code will not echo 2 but will print 1 twice

Comment: This is the only answer posted here that won't give you your output. https://3v4l.org/chlto

Answer (score 1):

This will work... tested and confirmed

```
$data = json_decode($json, true);
$count=0;
    foreach($data as $key => $val)
    {
       if($val['leader'] == 1)
       {
           $count++;
       }
    }
    echo $count;
```

Comment: IMO This is the best answer.  $count is being initialized so it wont throw a warning on increment and it's more memory efficient then my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by using the count function along with array_filter and json_decode.

```
echo count (array_filter(json_decode($json), 
                         function($a){ return $a->leader?1:0;}));
```

going from the inside out:

First json_decode makes the string into an array of stdClass objects

Then array_filter uses the call back to filter out entries where the leader property is false.

Finally count lets you know how many elements are in the returned array.